The internal transistor of LM311 seems to be conducting when it shouldn't
I have the following circuit, which compares two voltages, one of which is the reference voltage. I've simulated it in LTSpice using the model given by TI on their website and it works fine. After putting the circuit together, the emitter is sitting at 7 V even if the negative terminal is grounded and the positive terminal is higher, but the internal transistor should be turned off. The collector seems to be 7 V as well, even though it is connected to a 5 V battery. The supply voltage is 12 V.

I have noticed in the datasheet that the emitter is always connected to ground. Can I not use it in this configuration? That is, use the internal transistor as a switch? Also, it is odd why the emitter is sitting at 7 V given that the collector's voltage is at 5V. Anyone more experienced could explain what is wrong and how could it be fixed?

To fix your problem, simply change R18 from 10k to about 1k.  After making this change, the voltage at pin 1 should go from 0V when the comparator output transistor is OFF, to about 5V when it is ON (reduce R18 as required to get the HIGH voltage closer to 5V, particularly if the current out of pin 1 increases).  The voltage at pin 7 should stay close to 5V at all times.
With regard to the output transistor of the LM311: To explain why you are seeing 7V simultaneously at pin 1 (emitter) and pin 7 (collector) requires an understanding of the output stage of the LM311 comparator.  Here is the simplified schematic for the LM311 comparator from the datasheet:

Link for above image:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm311-n.pdf
Let's look in detail at the output stage (same image, zoomed in), which involves pins 8, 7, 1, & 4:

Q15 is the output transistor; this is ON when Q11 is ON, and OFF when Q11 is OFF.  (I will leave it as an exercise for the reader to determine which polarity at the input pins is required to turn Q11 ON and OFF.)
Your circuit has the following connections:
pin 8 to +12V,
pin 4 to GND,
pin 7 (output) to +5V via 10k (R18),
pin 1 to GND via 20k (R17 & R9) & a wire to some unknown load.
Let's assume the current in the wire leaving your schematic from R17 is negligible at all times.
When Q11 is OFF
When Q11 is OFF, then Q12 is OFF and Q15 is also OFF; pin 7 will go to 5V due to 10k pull-up (R18), and pin 1 will go to 0V (GND) due to 20k pull-down (R17 + R9).
When Q11 is ON
Now, when Q11 is ON its collector voltage (V(Q11c) tries to go up toward the +12V supply rail.  Q12 and Q15 form a Darlington voltage-follower, and so the emitter of Q15 (pin 1) will try to follow V(Q11c).  However, two auxiliary (protection) circuits prevent V(Q11c) from reaching +12V depending on external conditions:

Q16 & R13 (4Ω):
This limits the current out of pin 1 to between 150-200mA.

Q13 (diode) & Q14:
This limits the voltage at Q11c to about 1.4V (2 x Vbe) above the voltage at pin 7.  This prevents Q15 from becoming saturated (base-collector becoming forward biased), protecting Q15 from damage due to excessive base current, and speeding up its response time.


Q16 and Q14 both achieve this by shunting current away from the base of Q12.
What you are seeing is the result of aux circuit #2 operating, due to Q14 being turned on.  The voltage difference you are seeing between pin 7 & the +5V rail is due to the current flowing out of pin 7 and into R18, which is about 200uA (2V / 10k), while the current leaving pin 1 is 7V/20k = 350uA.  In other words, current is coming from the +12V supply and exiting out of both pin 1 (to GND) and pin 7 (to +5V).  The +5V supply is sinking the current out of pin 7.  The 200uA out of pin 7 is the sum of the current out of Q14 base and Q15 collector.

Here is a CircuitLab model that can be used to simulate the output stage of an LM311.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
One possibly very important difference between this model and a real LM311 is that this model uses models for 2N3904's and 2N3906's for the transistors. Obviously the transistors in the real LM311 are much smaller hence their scale current (\$I_S\$) will be smaller. The beta values are likely to be different as well. At one point in our analysis, we will see what looks to be an unusually large current to be found deep within an IC, i.e. over 5 mA. Keep that in mind.
The LM311 uses pins 7 and 1 for connections to the collector and emitter of a transistor used for output. However, the emitter and collector of this transistor (labeled Q15 in our schematic) are not connected only to pins 1 and 7, but are also connected to feedback lines.
The LM311 is designed so that the emitter of the output transistor can be connected to the negative rail of the comparator, or to ground, if that should be different from the negative rail, or the output transistor can be connected as a high side switch, and the emitter used as an output. Since when the transistor is on, the base must be biased relative to the emitter, the voltage at the base must vary with the voltage at the emitter. One approach to biasing the base would be to use a constant current source. The designers of the LM311 opted for something a bit more complicated. In addition supporting multiple configurations for the emitter, the LM311 also supports multiple configurations for the collector. The collector may be connected to the positive rail, for use in a high-side switch, or to a voltage higher than the positive rail, or it may be connected to a pull-down resistor for use as a low-side switch.
Let's begin to understand the workings of the output stage of an LM311 by considering the case where neither pin 1 nor pin 7 is connected to anything external. Notice I have added a from the base of Q11 to the negative rail. This results in the unusally high current I mentioned at the beginning. For now, it doesn't need to be such a high current, but later, to make our simulation match the experimental results of the OP, either it will need this particular value, or we will need different transistor models.

simulate this circuit
I have marked the paths that actually have current in them with red arrows. Note that there is no current in Q12, Q15 or Q16. This is because the only path that leads out of this circuit is through the collector of Q14. (Remember pins 1 and 7 are not connected to anything externally!) As a result, most of the nodes in the circuit are all at the same potential, i.e. the potential of the collector of Q11.
To make the circuit do anything useful, we therefore need to add a current outlet. We will do that by adding a voltage divider to pin 1, as is done per the OP.

simulate this circuit
Now current flows in the usual ways we would expect current to flow. Pin 7 shows a voltage of 7.833 V relative to the negative rail and pin 1 shows a voltage of 7.677 V.
What would happen if we connected a 7.833 V voltage source to pin 7 at this point? Essentially nothing. What if we added a voltage source with a higher voltage? Well, it would pull up pin 7. But the question that concerns us is what happens if we connect a voltage source that is lower than 7.833 V? Let's try it, and since we are following the OP, let's use a resistor between the voltage source and pin 7.

simulate this circuit
Much of the circuit looks the same, but Q15 is now operating in the reverse active region! (Conventional) current is flowing from the emitter to the collector! Apart from that, pin 1 has a voltage of 7.313 V and pin 7 has a voltage of 7.015 -- approximately what has been reported by the OP. However, here we have to confess that we "fudged" things to make this work out. It turns out that the voltages at pins 1 and 7 depend upon the current through the base of Q11. Getting pin voltages near 7 volts was the reason for the choosing the high current.

One other point that is highly worthy of mention. Q11 in this state is "super-saturated". It is so saturated that the current gain is less than 1!. Most of the current flows from emitter to base, and only a small portion is left over for the collector. Whether this "super-saturation" is the cause of the high current requirement (the collector current is only in the hundreds of uA) or whether the high current is an simulation artifact due to the use of discrete transistor models, or whether Q11 is indeed in a very odd state, due to the odd external configuration of the LM311 is a matter I don't have a definitive answer for.
